# how to show the dbms_output.put_line block which is there in if / end if condition

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
accept x char prompt 'Please enter y/n'

DECLARE
    user_input VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    user_input := '&x';
    IF user_input = 'y' THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('USER_INPUT is: ' || user_input);
    END IF;
    dbms_output.put_line('excluded accounts as of now:- 123,1234');
END;
```

I want to see the `dbms_output.put_line('USER_INPUT is: ' || user_input)` in serveroutput.

result

`USER_INPUT is: y`

Comment: If you are using a tool other than SQL\*Plus, you may need to configure it in some options/settings/toolbar to show you "server output" or "dbms output", however they might word it. Some tools make you take additional steps to enable it and have special tabs or screens for viewing it. If you ran the above in regular SQL\*Plus you'd see the text you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what your code does. Though, you can't avoid the 2nd `dbms_output.put_line` as it isn't *constrained* by any condition.

Tool you should use is SQL*Plus or SQL Developer; I'm not sure other tools will *understand* `accept` part of that code.

I'm entering `y`:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL> accept x char prompt 'Please enter y/n '
Please enter y/n y
SQL>
```

PL/SQL block displays it:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    user_input VARCHAR2(10);
  3  BEGIN
  4    user_input := '&x';
  5    IF user_input = 'y' THEN
  6       dbms_output.put_line('USER_INPUT is: ' || user_input);
  7    END IF;
  8    dbms_output.put_line('excluded accounts as of now:- 123,1234');
  9  END;
 10  /
old   4:   user_input := '&x';
new   4:   user_input := 'y';
USER_INPUT is: y
excluded accounts as of now:- 123,1234

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```